# Making new list based of if internal nested elements are the same in python

Tags: python, list, nested

Im trying to find a way to create a new list (list2) from a nested starting list (list1), if the elements in the starting lists meet certain conditions. The starting list is something like this,

```
list1=[[['1','1'],['1','2']], [['2','1'],['2','3']], [['3','3'],['3','1']]]
```

Id like to add all the elements from list1 into a new list made up of elements that have at least 1 nested element with the same number. For example both the first and third element(`[['1','1'],['1','2']]` and `[['3','3'],['3','1']]`) have at least one nested element (`['1','1'] and ['3','3']`) that have the same number, 1 and 1 in the first, and 3 and 3 in the other . So the new list would contain the first and third element from list1.

the new list should be,

```
list2=[[['1','1'],['1','2']], [['3','3'],['3','1']]]
```

My thought was to approach it like this,

```
list2=[]
for i in list1:
    for i in i:
        if i[0]==i[1]:
            list2.append(i)
```

however, this only gives out,

```
list2=[['1','1'], ['3','3']]
```

which is not exactly what I want. Any help of how to fix this, or if theres a better approach in general, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your second loop variable, you are overwriting the value of outer loop's counter in your inner loop:

```
for i in list1:
    for j in i:
        if j[0] == j[1]:
            list2.append(i)
```

If the inner list has more than 1 element, you can check if all elements are same or not by: `len(set(j)) == 1`.

Also, if the list satisfies the condition once, you should `break` from the inner loop, otherwise you would end up duplicates, inserting the same list again and again if it contains multiple inner lists with same values.

Comment: `for x, y in list1:  if x[0] == x[1]:  l.append([x, y])` and you'd neither need the nested *for* nor need to worry about a `break` statement.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help! Im wondering if I want to change up the conditions such that you would need at least two internal lists elements (like both ['1','1'], ['3','3'] in the same element) that have the same values instead of just one, would it be a matter of adding in another if loop with a third variable? Ive been trying that too but no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1=[[['1','1'],['1','2']], [['2','1'],['2','3']], [['3','3'],['3','1']]]
list2 = []
for i  in list1:
  for j in i:
    if(len(set(j)) == 1):
        list2.append(i)
print(list2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any() and set() may make your code easier to understand:

```
list1=[[['1','1'],['1','2']], [['2','1'],['2','3']], [['3','3'],['3','1']]]

list2 = []
for sublists in list1:
    if any(len(set(sub)) == 1 for sub in sublists):
        list2.append(sublists)

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[[['1', '1'], ['1', '2']], [['3', '3'], ['3', '1']]]
```